# Правильный контроллер

Tags: framework, php, yii, mvc

Изучаю Yii, вот в контроллере такое страшное есть:

```
$query_for_author = "delete from `author` where `id` = :author";
 $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query_for_author);
 $command->execute(array('author' => $author_for_delete['author_id']));
```

Или же вот:

```
Topic::model()->findBySql('SELECT * FROM topic WHERE title=:param', array(':param' => $find_topic));
```

Насколько я знаю, такого не должно быть в нем, типа запроса и т.п. Принял данные - отпрвил, все.
Как вы, товарищи разработчики, к такому относитесь? Или у вас тоже такое случается?

Comment: @Fikret, все правильно. Запросов (в идеале) даже в модели не должно быть - она запрашивает БД о получении тех или иных данных, но как это происходит, им всем (MVC) наплевать, пусть query builder / dbal разбирается. При правильном применении таких штук можно за полчаса перевести проект на новый движок БД и победно ухмыльнуться.

Comment: "Все правильно" = "правильно, что такого быть не должно", конечно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы написали, относится к простейшим выборкам, такое лучше делать средствами ORM:

```
Author::model()->deleteByPk($author_id);
```

По второму

```
Topic::model->findAllByAttributes(array('topic' => 'value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

:author - эта часть означает, что на это место будет помещена переменная. Таких параметров в запросе может быть множество. Например:

```
"delete from `author` where `id` = :author" AND `name` = :name;
```

Затем при выполнении запроса мы передаем значения этих параметров:

```
$command->execute(array('author' => $author_var, 'name'=>$name_var));
```

Comment: не, ну это понятно из PDO =)